# Make VueJS form to not submit on enter key

Tags: html, vue.js

I am wondering, is there way to disable the form submition on enter key press inside one of the input in Vue js. I am currently having simple form with button and one input and i am handling the submit with @submit.prevent="submitFunctionClickFunction"

Comment: The `@submit.prevent` should've prevented the form submission already. Where did you put that?

Answer (score 7):

Try adding `@keydown.enter.prevent` on the **input** field.